# Performance issues due to the lj_BC_TGETS of LUA JIT

Tags: linux, performance, kong, luajit, openresty

We currently using `Kong` as API Gateway, to route the traffic to our backend service.
About 3000 routes is maintained and most of them is `regex route`.

Recently, we experienced a significant increment of CPU usage after we  several API connected to `Kong`

In order to diagnostic the issue, we use `flame graph` to sample the CPU usage when alarm was triggered, here is the flame graph:
[image]

From the graph above, I suspected that the `lj_BC_TGETS`  was the underlying cause of problem ,however ,there is little information except `lj_BC_TGETS`  ,moreover, we don't know much about `lj_BC_TGETS` behind the screen,  any ideas?

Comment: `lj_BC_TGETS` is a field or method access in the interpreter, i.e. `obj.field`
or `obj:method`.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff any idea of this flame graph? `lj_BC_TGETS`  have a large part of it

Comment: Try to ask it on luajit mailing list